# json array loop thru nested not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to loop thru my nested array of json objetcs..

Here's the loop:

```
        $("#test").text("");
        for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
            $("#test").append(obj[i].line_item + ", ");
            for(var j=0;j<obj[i].length;j++){
                $("#test").append(obj[i][j].iid + ", ");
                $("#test").append(obj[i][j].name + ", ");
                $("#test").append(obj[i][j].price + ", ");
                $("#test").append(obj[i][j].lid + ", ");
                $("#test").append(obj[i][j].picture + "<br />");
            }//for for
        }//for
```

console.log i showing no errors, when i echo the php-script I get this output:

```
[{"line_item":"base","0":
{"iid":"1","name":"mix","price":"30","lid":"1","picture":"images\/mix.jpg"},
"1":{"iid":"2","name":"green","price":"30","lid":"1","picture":"images\/green.jpg"}}]
```

The problem:
When I loop thru the arrays i only get the output: base, in my html file.

My question: How can i get hold of the inner array objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to do this :

```
var a = [];

$.each(obj, function(i, arr) {
    a.push(arr.line_item);
    $.each(arr, function(j, ob) {
        if (typeof ob == 'object') {
            $.each(ob, function(key,value) {
                a.push(value)
            });
        }
    });
});

$("#test").text(a.join(', '));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4DA3R/)

Comment: This did the trick!! Thx a lot! Been wondering quit some time now!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using an object an not an array, so you can't do:

```
 obj[i].length
```

An easy easy way to solve that is to put the items inside an array, sample JSON:

```
[{"line_item":"base", "items": [
{"iid":"1","name":"mix","price":"30","lid":"1","picture":"images\/mix.jpg"},
{"iid":"2","name":"green","price":"30","lid":"1","picture":"images\/green.jpg"}]}]
```

And change your code to:

```
$("#test").text("");
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
  $("#test").append(obj[i].line_item + ", ");
  for(var j=0;j<obj[i]['items'].length;j++){
    var item = obj[i]['items'][j];
    $("#test").append(item.iid + ", ");
    $("#test").append(item.name + ", ");
    $("#test").append(item.price + ", ");
    $("#test").append(item.lid + ", ");
    $("#test").append(item.picture + "<br />");
  }//for for
}//for
```